# ¿Tengo que usar un foreach aquí?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo una suma del total de articulos que tengo en dos tablas. 
la consulta funciona bien y hace el calculo. Pero para lograr mostrar los resultados solo consigo sacarlos con un foreach. ¿De verdad la única forma de sacar ese dato es con un bucle?

La consulta es esta:

```
$CTotal = mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT SUM(PL.cantidad) Total FROM Pedidos_Linea PL, Pedidos P WHERE (PL.idpedido = P.id AND P.estado = 1 AND P.empresa = '.$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'].' AND P.borrado = 0)');
```

El dato de Total lo consigo sacar con este codigo:

```
 foreach($CTotal as $DTotal) {
echo 'Total: '.$DTotal["Total"];
}
```

¿No hay forma de que con una simple variable me de el dato?

Muchas gracias por vuestras sabias respuestas.

Comment: mysqli es algo limitado en la obtención de los datos. Lo que quieres quizá se logre de una manera simple con `fetch_row`, pero sólo en el caso de que estés esperando una sola fila en los resultados. Sería algo así: `if ($resultado = mysqli_query($Conectar, $sql)) { $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);` echo $fila[0]; }else{echo "No hay datos en la consulta";}` Aquí `$sql` representa tu consulta `SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes enviar la variable $CTotal como parámetro de la función [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) esta te devuelve un arreglo.

```
$CTotal = mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT SUM(PL.cantidad) Total FROM Pedidos_Linea PL, Pedidos P WHERE (PL.idpedido = P.id AND P.estado = 1 AND P.empresa = '.$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'].' AND P.borrado = 0)');
$CTotal = mysqli_fetch_all($CTotal);
```

Y ahí ya puedes usarlo de otra manera.

Comment: estoy probando con $CTotal["Total"] y no muestra nada :_(

Comment: Dale con $CTotal->Total  , o hazle un var_dump($CTotal) para que veas que llaves tiene

Answer (score 1):

Creo recordar en un proyecto que programe que la función devolvia un array. Entonces para forzar que sea un array de una fila podrías forzar el seleccionar una fila con `LIMIT 1`(añadir eso al final se la consulta del select) o hacer esto:

```
$result=mysqli_query($Conectar, 'SELECT SUM(PL.cantidad) Total FROM Pedidos_Linea PL, Pedidos P WHERE (PL.idpedido = P.id AND P.estado = 1 AND P.empresa = '.$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'].' AND P.borrado = 0)');
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['Total'];
/*si no sale prueba esto, porque creo seguirá siendo un array pero al ponerlo asociativo sabes que el valor de 'Total' será el valor que buscabas. */
echo $row[0]['Total'];.
```

Como sabes que esa consulta solo tiene una fila podrías obtenerlo.